# Can't commit to an existing github repository in a batch script

Tags: git, github, push, commit, pull

I have made the following batch script to automatically run a program and commit a csv file to my repository. The pass is filled in with my real password. I delete the existing local repo, so that the clone command gets the most recent clean version each time. Whenever I run this, I get:

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed
> to push some refs to
> 'https://github.com/maxbear123/Knox-County-Covid-19-Risk-Assesment.git'
> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is
> behind hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes
> (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note
> about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

```
:: @echo off
call C:\Users\maxbear123\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
call conda activate Scraper
call cd C:\Users\maxbear123\Documents\Python_Scripts
call python COVID-19_School_Risk_Data_Logger.py
call del Knox-County-Covid-19-Risk-Assesment /Q
call git clone https://maxbear123:pass@github.com/maxbear123/Knox-County-Covid-19-Risk-Assesment
call git add historical_predictions.csv
call git commit -m"Automated Prediction Update"
call git push https://maxbear123:pass@github.com/maxbear123/Knox-County-Covid-19-Risk-Assesment.git
cmd /k
```

Can someone please tell me how to actually do this? I've searched online a ton and tried a bunch of stuff that didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that it is trying to run the output of `git commit`

Comment: `:pass` Does the password contain any special characters like `<|>"&^%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The following script will work for this:

```
:: @echo off
call C:\Users\maxbear123\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
call conda activate Scraper
call cd C:\Users\maxbear123\Documents\Python_Scripts\Knox-County-Covid-19-Risk-Assesment
call git init 
call git pull https://maxbear123:pass@github.com/maxbear123/Knox-County-Covid-19-Risk-Assesment
call python COVID-19_School_Risk_Data_Logger.py
call git add historical_predictions.csv
call git commit -m"Automated Prediction Update"
call git push https://maxbear123:pass@github.com/maxbear123/Knox-County-Covid-19-Risk-Assesment.git
```

Essentially, I didn't understand fundamentally how git worked.

For anyone else with similar ignorance this is the processs:

To Start Committing to an existing repository:

1. clone https://user:password@github.com/user/repo
2. cd into the the cloned repo (now a dir on your computer)
3. init
4. edit or add files
5. add those added/edited files
6. commit -m”message”
7. push https://user:password@github.com/user/repo

To continue committing to an existing repository:

1. cd into the previously cloned repo (a dir on your computer)
2. init
3. pull https://user:password@github.com/user/repo
4. edit or add files
5. add those added/edited files
6. commit -m”message”
7. push https://user:password@github.com/user/repo